# Node.js+MongoDB can't save hashed password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save password in MongoDB but have error:

```
Error: User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required.
```

Model:

```
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    isActivated: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    activationLink: {type: String},
})

module.exports = model('User', UserSchema)
```

create user:

```
        const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
        const UserModel = require('../models/user-model');
        ...
        const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        console.log(`email => ${email} pass => ${hashPassword}`);
        const user = await UserModel.create({email, hashPassword});
```

Log shows that password hash created:

email => lll@google.com pass => $2a$10$4IV2Q0ZncWHInfT89Fwl.eCxCgvykvY.uqlvq0GNSeDJ/6Q83T7nK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> const user = await UserModel.create({email, hashPassword});

If you pass `hashPassword` variable, it will take as `hashPassword` field.
Change your code like this:

```js
const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
const user = await UserModel.create({email, password: hashPassword});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Re-create your model using these lines of code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true
 },
 password: {
  type: String,
  required: false,
  minlength: 8
 },
 activationLink: {
  type: String,
  trim: false
 },    
 isActivated: {
   type: Boolean,
   default: false
 }
 },{
  timestamps: true
 }
)

userSchema.methods.isPasswordMatch = async function (password) {
 const user = this
 return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
}

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  const user = this
  if (user.isModified('password')) {
   user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8)
  }
 next()
})

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```